# How to anchor an element by its bottom coordinate rather than its top

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am making a poker table using react. Right now I have player components that need to be positioned around a table.

[image]

The issue I am having is that the player boxes change when the screen attribute is changed, which is what I want, but the position of the top two is anchored to the top, which causes the players to be moved away from the table. I would rather have the anchor on the bottom, so that they will stay next to the table.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using absolute positioning here, you can do something like:

```
.player {
    top: 200px; /* whatever value you want the bottom of element to be from top */
    margin-top: -100%; /* bring the element back up so the bottom is where the top value set above is */
}
```

That said I'd advise using something like CSS tables or flexbox here.

Comment: I need to be able to layer chips, pots, and bets on top of the table image and make everything resize when screen-size changes. Would that be possible if I use CSS tables or flexbox?

Comment: The tricky part would be putting anything on the curved corners of the table. If you just want to put things in front of the people, flexbox or CSS tables could do that. It effectively divides up the table into a grid. If you don't want a grid style layout though and want more freedom to move things around, then maybe it's not for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is by default that the origin is always located at the `top left` portion of the element. To achieve your desired results you need to add the height of the element always if you want it to anchor at bottom left like.

```
elem.X = X;
elem.Y = Y + elem.height;
```

hope that helps